# PyQt6 - Open QWidget by left clicking the SystemTrayIcon

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I am new to PyQt6 and python. I created a class `SystemTrayIcon` where I am trying to open a QWidget `win` which was created outside the `SystemTrayIcon`-class, to show up when the SystemTrayIcon got **left-clicked**.

I got this error: `"name 'win' is not defined"`

How can I fix this, that the `win`-QWidget which was created outside the class `SystemTrayIcon` will open when the SystemTrayIcon got **left-clicked**?

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
import sys
import ui_main


class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, win, parent=None):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip("Test SystemTray")

        menu = QMenu(parent)
        exit_ = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exit_.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())

        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.activated.connect(self.trayiconclicked)

    def trayiconclicked(self, reason):
        if reason == self.ActivationReason.Trigger:
            print("SysTrayIcon left clicked")
            win.show() ###### -> ERROR: (<class 'NameError'>, NameError("name 'win' is not defined"), <traceback object at 0x000001B04F5C9580>)


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    win = QWidget()

    tray_icon = SystemTrayIcon(QIcon("images/logo.png"), win)
    tray_icon.setVisible(True)
    tray_icon.show()

    ui = ui_main.Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(win, tray_icon.geometry().right(), tray_icon.geometry().bottom(),
               tray_icon.geometry().width(), tray_icon.geometry().height())
    ui.btn_close.clicked.connect(lambda: win.close())

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: `win` is defined in the *local* scope of `run()`, it's not available outside of it. It *will* work, though, if you remove that function and put everything in that block inside the `if __name__`, in that case all the variables defined in there become global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work now you need to make `win` its attribute before you call it

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, win, parent=None):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        self.setToolTip("Test SystemTray")
        self.win = win  # <----- name it whatever you want ie self.abc will also work

        menu = QMenu(parent)
        exit_ = menu.addAction("Exit")
        exit_.triggered.connect(lambda: sys.exit())

        self.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.activated.connect(self.trayiconclicked)

    def trayiconclicked(self, reason):
        if reason == self.ActivationReason.Trigger:
            print("SysTrayIcon left clicked")
            self.win.show()  # <--- if you named you attribute self.abc call self.abc here instead of self.win
```

NOTE:
to make a variable a attribute of a class you need to define it with self eg, here I want to have age as a attribute

```py
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name, age):
      # assigning attributes
      self.age = age
   def some_method(self):
      # here calling self.name will give you error because you didn't assign it as a attribute 
      print(self.name)
   def some_method_1(self):
      # here this will not give error as you have assigned it earlier as a attribute
      print(self.age) 

p = Person("Bob", 16)
p.some_method_1()
p.some_method()
```